# Xamarin iOS: Webview add page on navigation stack with javascript

Tags: javascript, xamarin, xamarin.ios

On my Xamarin iOS app, I want to programmatically make the user navigate from one web page to another ( http://a --> http://a/b ). I tried doing

```
webView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl("http:..")));
```

But the previous session is lost and new session is created. Is there a better way where instead of reloading the whole url I can just navigate them to next page.

I know that to go back to previous page we can use

```
webView.EvaluateJavaScript("history.go(-1);", null);
```

is there anything similar on javascript to move forward ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I can do that by :

```
webView.EvaluateJavaScript("window.location.href = 'http://a/b';", null);
```